# Charts with multiple axes in Apache Wicket with ShieldUI

Tags: java, charts, wicket, shieldui

I'm trying to render a chart with multiple y axis with shieldUi apache wicket integration.

When charts had one y axis I was used to add y axis by doing:

```
chart.getOptions().getAxisY().getTitle().setText("the y title");
```

Now that I have 3 axes with title "title1", "title2", "title3" I'm not able to render them in java (while I did it in javascript).

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Laura

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to change axisY to List type in che shield-ui wicket code and works fine!

Laura

Answer (score 1):

They have just updated the [wicket-shieldui](https://github.com/shieldui/wicket-shieldui) GitHub repo to allow multiple defined axes at the same time.